# NGINX rewrite to public with /

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

Tried the search but didn't found a solution yet. I am trying to get the next url working a nice urls..

URL.com/public/index.php?url=admin/loginform
to
URL.com/admin/loginform

I tried to set the root folder and a location ~^ /public/ directive but can't get it to work.

```
location / {
    root /srv/URL.com/public/
    try_files $uri $uri/.php $uri/ /index.php?url=$args;
}
```

I am trying to transfer from .htaccess to nginx..

Root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ public/  [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then public:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Does somebody knows how to map it correctly?

Thanks

Comment: facing the same issue.